# Extract JSON HTTP Request from .java file to use with Alamofire Swift?

Tags: android, json, swift, alamofire

I've decompiled .apk file, containing source code java files.
I want to use the same java script but with ***Swift*** and ***Alamofire Framework*** using the code

> Alamofire.request("http://example.com/search", parameters: parameters)

So, back to the java class > it's requesting POST HTTP request with certain parameters, I'd like to know the parameters to Parse JSON from another iOS application.
So, the script link is http://example.com/search , but need the parameters.

The method requesting the script is :

```
public SearchController Build() {
    Utility.hideViews(this.errorLayout);
    new SimpleStringRequest().setUrl(getActivity().getResources().getString(C1133R.string.base_url) + getActivity().getResources().getString(C1133R.string.search)).setParams(setParams()).setmSwipeRefreshLayout(getSwipeRefreshLayout()).Request(1).setOnSimpleJsonResponse(this);
    return this;
}
```

I've managed to know

```
C1133R.string.base_url = http://example.com
C1133R.string.search = /search
```

I'd like to know the ***setParams()*** values .